# Matching a word with dot symbol using regexp javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a search feature. I want to check if the user enter a text word/sentence with dot (.) on it.

```
Example:
-anyword.anyword.
-.
-.anyword
```

Once I detect that he/she entered a value that has a dot on it I will consider that as invalid.

I know I can do this using regexp but I'm still in the process of learning it. So anyone could shed me a light here would be appreciated :).

Comment: `if (/\./.test(str)) { ... }`

Comment: @elclanrs, that's an answer...

Comment: Test your regex with http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/ as its easy to use and helpful while learning.

Comment: @elclanrs I updated my question. The word test can mean anyword.

Comment: @WonderingCoder: `test` is a method of `RegExp` not literally "test".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `String#indexOf`:

```
if (theString.indexOf(".") !== -1) {
    // It has a dot
}
```

But if you really want to use regular expressions (which would be overkill for just finding a `.`):

```
if (/\./.test(theString)) {
    // It has a dot
}
```

The `/\./` part is the regular expression. The beginning and ending `/` are the regex delimiters, like `"` and `'` are for strings. The *content* of the regex is `\.` We need the backslash before the `.` because otherwise, within a regex, `.` means "match any character". The backslash before it "escapes" it and tells the regex to literally match a dot. (We don't need that in the `String#indexof` example because `indexOf` doesn't have any special handling of `.`.)

Comment: I just love the whole explanation for the code, makes it so clear and understandable, wish all answers would inspire on this one (even mine).

Answer (score 2):

Better to use `indexOf` function of `String` then `Regexp` for this as `Regexp` will be an overkill in this scnerio:

Use **`MyString.indexOf('.')` if it return -1** there is no dot in the string. If returned value is some integer like 0,1,2 etc that gives the position of Dot in the string. So -1 tell that there is no Dot

Example:

```
if(MyString.indexOf('.') === -1)
{
   //No Dot is there, continue search
}
else
{
   //Invalid string, dot is present
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**try this**

The `indexOf()` method returns the position of the first occurrence of a specified value in a string.

This method returns `-1` if the value to search for never occurs.

```
var str = "test.test";
if(str.indexOf('.') === -1){
  alert("no dot found.");
}
else{
    alert("dot found.");
}
```